# How can I solve this linear optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints

I've come across a question which I was not able to solve I would appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Q) Given the constraints,

$$x \ge 0$$
$$y \ge 0$$ 
$$x + y \le1$$

which of the following is likely to be an optimal solution if the objective is to minimise $~ax + by~$ for any real numbers $~a~$ and $~b~$?

These are the options available:
$$\text{a) }(0,0)$$
$$\text{b) }(1,1)$$
$$\text{c) }(1,0)$$
$$\text{d) }(0,1)$$
$$\text{e) }(a,b)$$

Comment: Probably $x=y=0$??

Comment: You have a single-variable problem since you have the condition $x+y ≤ 1$. Then any possible maxima and minima must occur on the boundaries.

Comment: @TobyMak Indeed, so the minimum is $\min\{0,a,b\}$.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit Maybe an explanation would be appreciated? It's a choose the correct answer type question.

Comment: @TobyMak Can you explain it a bit and provide an answer below?

Comment: it's obvious that if $a,b \ge0$ then the minimum possible value they can attain is $0$ which happens at $x=y=0$.

Comment: @balachandarvadigacherla You can also input each of the values given and try to find the minimum out of those.

Comment: Suppose $a,b,x,y>0$. Can you change at least one of $x$ or $y$ to decrease the value of $ax+by$? Similarly, suppose that $a<b<0$, with $x+y<1$. Can you change at least one of $x$ or $y$ to decrease $ax+by$? Suppose now instead that $x+y=1$ with $y>0$, keeping the value of $a$ and $b$ fixed. Can you change $x$ and $y$ simultaneously so as to continue respecting the constraints, while decreasing $ax+by$? Hint: the answer to each of my previous questions is yes.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit Should I input those values in place of (a, b)? If so how can I know other values i.e x, y to find the minimum?

Comment: @balachandarvadigacherla Input these values in $x,y$!

Answer (score 2):

In a linear optimisation problem, the optimal solution (minimum or maximum) are always on the vertex of the constraint polygon.

In the problem here, the constraint polygon is a triangle whose vertex are at $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  On which vertex is the minimum depends on the value of $a$ and $b$.

Let first evaluate the function $ax+by$ at these points.
$$a\cdot 0 + b \cdot 0 = 0$$
$$a\cdot 1 + b \cdot 0 = a$$
$$a\cdot 0 + b \cdot 1 = b$$

If $a,b > 0$, then the minumum will be at $(0,0)$

If either $a$ or $b$ is below $0$ then the minimum will be at smallest value.  E.g. if $a<0$ and $a < b$ then the minimum will be at $(1,0)$

There are three special cases to consider.

1- If $a=0$ and $b>0$, then any point on the lattice between $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ is a minimum of the function.

2- If $b=0$ and $a>0$, then any point on the lattice between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ is a minimum of the function.

1- If $a<0$ and $b<0$ and $a=b$, then any point on the lattice between $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ is a minimum of the function.